# Icons in Unity Panel showing incorrectly in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: indicator, 16.10, notification-area

The Slack and WebTorrent Desktop apps usually have nice top bar icons but sometimes they appear like so:

[image: icons in top bar shown broken]

Is there a way to solve this problem?